# Crear desde cero una base de datos oracle en servidor remoto

Tags: c#, oracle

Saluds a todos.

Estoy haciendo un programa indeoendiente de la base de datos, utilizando System.Data.Common, DBProviderfactory, etc; necesito crear desde cero una base de datos en un servidor oracle, y posteriormente crear las tablas, procedimientos almacenados y funciones; el programa se ejecuta desde una ubicación distinta al servidor oracle. Esto ya lo he hecho con un servidor SQL Server y ahora necesito hacerlo con oracle.

Comparto el código para SQL Server:

```
dpf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dp); //dp = "System.Data.SqlClient"

conexion = dpf.CreateConnection();
using (conexion)
{
     //Cadena de conexión a la master para crear la base de datos
     this.conexion.ConnectionString =
          "server=" + this.txt_SD_Servidor.Text +
          ";database=master" +
          ";user id=" + this.txt_SD_UserId.Text +
          ";password=" + this.txt_SD_Pwd.Text;
     this.conexion.Open();

     dbcmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
     dbcmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE " + this.txt_SD_BD.Text;
     dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     conexion.Close();

     //Cadena de conexión a la nueva base de datos para crear las tablas, procedimientos y funciones.
     this.conexion.ConnectionString = this.txt_CnStr.Text;
     this.conexion.Open();

     dbcmd = conexion.CreateCommand();

     dbcmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE ..."
     dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     dbcmd.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE ..."
     dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     dbcmd.CommandText = "CREATE FUNCTION ..."
     dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

No tengo ninguna experiencia trabajando con oracle, sólo lo he utilizado para conectarme a basse de datos ya existentes y manipular registros.

He visto un ejemplo en un post anterior, pero en este post utilizan un servidor local, es decir, que el programa está en el mismo ordenador que oracle.

Este es el enlace al Post:

[Create Oracle database and schema programmatically ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056794/create-oracle-database-and-schema-programmatically-ado-net)

Como se puede ver en el post anterior, la ubicación de la ruta de oradata es local:

```
string oracleDataPath = "C:\\PATH_TO_ORADATA\\";
```

Yo necesito hacer lo mismo pero direccionándolo a un servidor remoto.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: porque tienes que creas la db y las tablas usando codigo? no puedes crearla mediante un script. Quizas crear tablas o modificarlas puedas hacerlo con scripting desde codigo, pero no creo que puedas crear la db. Recomendaria primero logres crear la db usando el `CREATE DATABASE` pero desde un manager conectado al servidor, si logras eso se podria ver como llevarlo a codigo

Comment: Una BD en Oracle es completamente diferente a SQL Server, vas a necesitar forzosamente conectarte al servidor donde quieres la BD y de ahi ejecutar el script para crear tu BD y luego tablas SPs.

Comment: Buenos días.
Lo que ocurre es que estoy desarrollando un sistema que se instalará posteriormente en cualquier empresa, y no tengo porqué obligar a tengan un determinado DBMS, la idea es que la empresa no tenga que hacer nada, simplemente instalarle el sistema usando su DBMS. Hay un módulo indepe3ndiente del sistema que es con el que configura los datos de la empresa, datos seervidor y otros datos de configuración.

Se piden los datos de conexión al servidor y es en este momento que se crea la base de datos según el tipo de servidor que se haya seleccionado (SQL Server, oracle, mySQL, etc.)

Comment: Esta respuesta y la anterior son para Leandro.

Yo cree la base de datos en el servidor oracle indicando que guarde los scripts, pero el primero es un archivo bat que crea las carpetas para la base de datos, 7 screipts sql y 2 archivos .ora. Creo que no se va a poder hacer. Tendré que pedir que creen la base de datos vacía y crear el contenido desde el programa de instalación/configuración.

Comment: Para dbamex:
Creo que para el caso de oracle lo que haré será ejecutar el instalador/configurador en el mismo servidor de base de datos y crearla como si estuviera en un servidor local como se muestra en el enlace. Probaré esa opción.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda